# Prove that every 2 dimensional FG-Module with gh not equal to hg is irreducible.

Tags: representation-theory, modules

Basically the questions is as follows.

Suppose that $V$ is a 2-Dimensional $FG$-Module where F=The complex numbers and that there exists $g,h$ elements of $G$  and $v$ an element in $V$ such that $(gh).v\neq (hg).v$, ie there is $g, h$ and $v$ such that when $gh$ acts on $v$ you dont get the same result as when $hg$ acts on $v$. Show that V is irreducible.

I assume this is equivalent to saying that the group is non abelian as if not gh would equal hg for all g,h. So far i have had a stab at it and this is what i have come up with so far. Using maschkes theorem we know that letting U be a  proper submodule of V then there exists W such that V is equal to the direct sum of U and W (U and W are both submodules of V) this then leads to 2 posibiliies either the dimension of one of them is zero and the other has dimension 2, this would lead to one being V and the other being {zero} and if these were the only 2 submodules we would have proven irreducibility of V however there could be 2 submodules both of diemsnion 1. At this point i have started to play around with projections onto U and projections onto W, aswell as schurs lemma etc, but i dont really know how to progress from this point.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An $FG$-module $M$ defines a homomorphism $\rho$ from $G$ into the group of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$, where $n$ is the dimension of $M$. What do you know about $\rho(G)$ if $n=1$? What do you know about the direct product of two such groups?

Comment: Note that to apply Maschke's theorem, you need to assume that the characteristic of $F$ does not divide the order of $G$ (you do not seem to assume anything about $F$ in the question).

Comment: Sorry the field in question is the complex numbers and as such I have edited the question.

Comment: The main problem is so far during our representation course we havent define a direct product and the way an FG module has been defined is in terms of a group action acting on a vector space. and when we are talking about a homomorphism from G to the group of matrices order n we are talking about a representation and that it is easy to interchange between the two.

Comment: Have you used the word “faithful”?

Comment: Yes we have the definition that  an fg module V is faithful if g.v=v for all v in V then g=e (the identity of G) and only e.

Comment: Ie the only group element to fix all v is the identity